# QString::mid() always returns the same result

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

This function should split a QString by (almost) equal fragments:

```
QStringList splitCell(const QString& cell) const
{
    QStringList result;

    const int currentSize = cell.size();
    const int fragmentCount = currentSize / c_maxCellSize + (currentSize % c_maxCellSize ? 1 : 0); // c_maxCellSize = 32758
    const int fragmentSize = currentSize / fragmentCount + (currentSize % fragmentCount ? 1 : 0);

    for (int fragment = 0; fragment < fragmentCount; ++fragment)
    {
        QString currentFragment = cell.mid(fragmentSize * fragment, fragmentSize);
        result << currentFragment;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But if fragmentCount > 1 then currentFragment is always the same in every iteration. What's wrong?
P.S. The cell string may be large (up to 100K symbols)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal self-contained example reproducing the problem?

Comment: works just fine for me. Nevertheless is your `fragmentSize` always `c_maxCellSize` if more than one fragment, isn't it?

Comment: @SebastianLange No, if cell.size() < c_maxCellSize then fragmentSize == cell.size()

Comment: @LibertyPaul Then its only one fragment though

Comment: @SebastianLange Just as planned. If cell.size() > c_maxCellSize than it will split to more strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a compiler problem (MS VS2008-dinosaur edition).
After a couple of  rebuilds it works fine.